# Inkscape: turning thin long shapes into paths

Tags: inkscape, file-conversion

### Core problem

I have an SVG which contains long thin rectangles where it should have a line:

[image]

Is there a way to change/convert these somehow? (For example with a script "if aspect ratio > 20, create a path running through the symmetry axis".)

### Background / Prior efforts

I have an HTML file with many boxes with a border. I want to convert this file into a vector format for laser cutting. This requires the borders to be *paths*, i.e., without an area.

I've tried many tools [evopdf](https://www.evopdf.com/demo/HTML_to_Image/HTML_to_SVG.aspx) and [many other similar conversion sites](https://onlineconvertfree.com/complete/html-azw3/), tools like [webvector](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/webvector/), [cutycapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/), [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/), but none works sufficiently well and often the result looks only vaguely like what the browser renders.

What works best is to have the browser (firefox) render the page and then use "print as pdf". I then import the resulting file into inkscape, which looks the way it did in the browser, and has the correct sizes as were set in the html file (they were set in mm). The only issue is the one described above.

I tried on both linux and windows.

If there is another pdf printer that does correctly create paths, that would also solve my issue.

Many thanks

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can't you simply redraw the shapes as paths with strokes?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I could do it manually that way, but there are many shapes, and I need to do this more often than just this once. So I'd prefer a structural/automated solution.